# RE-show previous Userform

Tags: excel, userform, private-methods, vba

i have a series of userforms that will run in sequence, and i need a button that can RE-show the previous userform, i've tried the code below but it gives a error telling me that this userform has already been show, i'm clueless about how to get this done, here is the code:

```
Private Sub RETORNAR_Click()

Unload Me

' ETAPA_01 is the previous userform

ETAPA_01.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try creating another sub with only `ETAPA_01.Show` and calling it in this code instead of  `ETAPA_01.Show`

Comment: add your line `ETAPA_01.Show` in `userform_Terminate` (or `userform_queryclose`), or you could also reverse your 2 lines of code, first show (maybe as vbmodless?) then unload old ; or 3rd solution : `Me.hide`, `Etapa_01.show`, `unload me`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to identify what might be wrong with your existing code from the snippet you provide.

I have created two approaches that give the effect you seek although I suspect a mixture will give the most satisfactory solution.

I created a new workbook and within it I created six user forms: `frmTest01` to `frmTest06`.  On each form I creates two command buttons named `cmdBack` and `cmdForward`.  I saved the workbook and created two copies.

For version A, the switching between forms is handled by a macro outside the forms.  The code for each user form is:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
  Direction = -1
  Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub cmdForward_Click()
  Direction = 1
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

That is, the two exits routines unload their form after setting a global variable `Direction` to indicate whether the user wants to move back to the previous form or forward to the next.  All the complexity is in the calling macro which is:

```
Option Explicit
  Public Direction As Long
Sub CtrlForms()

  Dim FormCrnt As Long

  FormCrnt = 0

  Do While True

    Select Case FormCrnt
      Case 0
        FormCrnt = FormCrnt + 1
        Load frmTest01
        frmTest01.Show
      Case 1
        If Direction = 1 Then
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt + 1
          Load frmTest02
          frmTest02.Show
        Else
          Exit Sub
        End If
      Case 2
        If Direction = 1 Then
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt + 1
          Load frmTest03
          frmTest03.Show
        Else
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt - 1
          Load frmTest01
          frmTest01.Show
        End If
      Case 3
        If Direction = 1 Then
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt + 1
          Load frmTest04
          frmTest04.Show
        Else
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt - 1
          Load frmTest02
          frmTest02.Show
        End If
      Case 4
        If Direction = 1 Then
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt + 1
          Load frmTest05
          frmTest05.Show
        Else
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt - 1
          Load frmTest03
          frmTest03.Show
        End If
      Case 5
        If Direction = 1 Then
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt + 1
          Load frmTest06
          frmTest06.Show
        Else
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt - 1
          Load frmTest04
          frmTest04.Show
        End If
      Case 6
        If Direction = 1 Then
          Exit Sub
        Else
          FormCrnt = FormCrnt - 1
          Load frmTest05
          frmTest05.Show
        End If
    End Select

  Loop

End Sub
```

Direction -1 from `frmTest01` and direction +1 from `frmTest06`, results in an exit the macro.  In all other situation, the appropriate user form is loaded and shown.

For approach B, the complexity is in the user forms.  Here the calling macro is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CtrlForms()

  Load frmTest01
  Load frmTest02
  Load frmTest03
  Load frmTest04
  Load frmTest05
  Load frmTest06

  frmTest01.Show

  Unload frmTest01
  Unload frmTest02
  Unload frmTest03
  Unload frmTest04
  Unload frmTest05
  Unload frmTest06

End Sub
```

That is, this macro is only responsible for loading and unloading the forms and showing the first.

The code for each of the forms:

frmUser01

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
  Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub cmdForward_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest02.Show
End Sub
```

frmUser02

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest01.Show
End Sub
Private Sub cmdForward_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest03.Show
End Sub
```

frmUser03

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest02.Show
End Sub
Private Sub cmdForward_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest04.Show
End Sub
```

frmUser04

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest03.Show
End Sub
Private Sub cmdForward_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest05.Show
End Sub
```

frmUser05

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest04.Show
End Sub
Private Sub cmdForward_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest06.Show
End Sub
```

frmUser06

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
  Me.Hide
  frmTest05.Show
End Sub
Private Sub cmdForward_Click()
   Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Back from `frmTest01` and forward from `frmTest06` hide their form and exit back to the controlling macro.  All others hide their form and show the next form.

Both these approaches give the control you seek.

I suspect the best approach is to load all the forms at the beginning and unload all at the end with hide the old form and show the new rather than unload and load during processing.  I prefer to localise flow control so I would use the `Select` statement from approach A but without the loads.

Comment: I used the hide aproach, it fits better with the rest of the code and it's functions, thx man =]